# Positional argument in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm studiyng Adaline GSD algorithm and I have an error that says `TypeError: activation () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. How I interpretate that? There are two variables in that line?

I know my code looks long, but most are methods

My code is:

```
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=50, shuffle=True, random_state =None) :
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter=n_iter
        self.w_initialized=False
        self.shuffle=True
        self.random_state = random_state 

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self._initialize_weights(X.shape[1])
        self.cost_=[]
        for i in range (self.n_iter):
            if self.shuffle:
                X, y= self._shuffle(X,y)
            cost =[]
            for xi, target in zip(X,y):
                cost.append(self._update_weights(xi,target))
            avg_cost=sum(cost)/len(y)
            self.cost._append(avg_cost)
        return self

    def partial_fit(self,X,y):
        if not self.w_initialized:
            self._initialize_weights(X.shape[1])
        if y.ravel().shape[0]>1:
            for xi, target in zip(X,y):
                self._update_weights(xi, target)

        else:
            self._update_weights(X,y)
        return self

    def _shuffle(self,X,y):
        r=self.rgen.permutation(len(y))
        return X[r], y[r]

    def _initialize_weights(self,m):
        self.rgen= np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.w_=self.rgen.normal(loc= 0.0, scale= 0.01, size= 1+m)
        self.w_initialized=True

    def _update_weights(self, xi, target):
        output= self.activation(self.net_input(xi))
        error=(target- output)
        self.w_[1:] += self.eta * xi.dot(error)
        self.w_[0] += self.eta * error
        cost= 0.5*error**2
        return cost

    def net_input(self,X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:])+ self.w_[0]

    def activation(X):
        return X

    def predict(self,X):
        return np.where(self.activation(self.net_input(X)) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

It is not all my code, but is enaugh.
How can I write `output= self.activation(self.net_input(xi))` without getting an error like that?

Comment: "activation" needs a "self" parameter or should be declared as "@staticmethod".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `self` to your function. This should fix the issue:

```
def activation(self, X): 
    return X
```

Anytime you're calling a class method with `self.` prepended to the variable `self` is automatically passed as the first parameter and any values provided within the parentheses are passed as additional parameters.